# Subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ not a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have this question for homework and I can't figure it out.

Find a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ that is not a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ but adheres to closure.

In other words, a subset whose elements when added are elements of the subset, but it is not a subgroup.  I've been stumped on this.  All $n\mathbb{Z}, n\in{\mathbb{N}}$ are subgroups, the odd numbers don't work since they sum to even numbers.  I tried utilizing some cosets of $n\mathbb{Z},$ but can't see them there either.  ANy hints or help is appreciated.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ unless $n=0$. Hint: What must go wrong is that either $0$ is not in the subset, or some element in the subset has its inverse not in the subset.

Comment: I meant to have just $n\mathbb{Z}$, not the quotient group...  My intuition was that as you mentioned, 0 would most likely not be an element.  But I'm still stumped.

Comment: Well, think of what the smallest set you can make is that contains $1$ and is closed under addition. Can you make this set without including $0$?

Comment: Oh wait, it is simply $\mathbb{N}$?  That would do it right?

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Comment: The empty set is closed, trivially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naturals $\;\Bbb N\;$

The positive multiples of $\;n\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb N\;$

The negative multiples of $\;n\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ ...

Comment: couldn't we just adjoin $\{0\}$ too so we have the Whole numbers $\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$? Even though it includes the additive identity, the inverses are not in the set so the inverse axiom for a group fails?

Comment: Yes, also that.